# Building tests for json.net fails

Tags: json.net, visual-studio-2015

When trying to build the tests for Json.net in Visual Studio 2015, they fail on unresolved references:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Attempting to restore the nuget packages fails with an error:

> Dependency '"Newtonsoft.Json": ""' has invalid version specification.

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me after *fresh checkout* and for solution Newtonsoft.Json.Net40.sln:

1. In folder Newtonsoft.Json.Tests, open file "project.json" and remove dependency to Newtonsoft.Json, so dependency node will be an empty array. Also remove completely "dnxcore50" node.
2. Open solution and in Package Manager run "Install-Package NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework" for project Newtonsoft.Json.Tests.Net40
3. Build solution

Now you should be able to run tests.